# How are nodes incentivised to be honest when approving transactions?

Tags: transaction, tangle, node, validation

I am new to IOTA and would like to understand **how nodes are incentivised to be truthful when approving transactions**?

**Bitcoin:**

Say a miner approves a tx that is invalid (say bc it double spends). It mines it into a block. It gets X btc for doing that.

Problem: it is a on a "historical path" that others do no recognise so its X btc are worthless.

Conclusion, it won't want to approve invalid tx.

**IOTA:**

A node verifies two tx. Say one of them happens to be invalid.

**What happens next?**

Answer (score 1):

By verifying a transaction that is invalid, a transaction itself becomes invalid and will never be verified by other honest transactions (i.e. the transaction is on an "invalid path" that others do not recognize so its X Iotas are worthless).

So:

> **What happens next?**

Nothing. The transaction that happens to verify an invalid one will never be confirmed.

---

For details, take a look at [Iotas Tip-Selection Algorithm Documentation](https://hackmd.io/s/Skow-8Hb7#).

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how "By verifying a transaction that is invalid, a transaction itself becomes invalid" please?

Comment: @hartmut I added a link. Your question is addressed in section 3.3